# I can't http request in localhost

Tags: express, google-chrome, networking, localhost, httprequest

I want to use localhost as a server. I can receive index.html on the browser, but I can't send data to the server with "post" method in Html.
are there any properties for interaction with localhost in the chrome browser?

[HTTP request in the network of chrome developer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbkBQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to change the `type` of button to `submit` in the HTML file. :)

```html
<button type="submit">Calculate</button>
```